# I want to have an imageView be a perfect square regardless of the height

Tags: android, xml, imageview, height, width

I have an `imageView` in a row layout which I use for a `recyclerView`. The **height** of this `imageView` is set to `match_parent`, but for it to be a perfect square I can't hard-code the **width** of the `imageView`.

What I need is a way to set the **width** of the `imageView` to be exactly the same as the **height** of the `imageView` when it is displayed, since setting the width to `wrap_content` or `match_parent` throws the rest of the layout off since it is rectangular, sizeable images.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public class FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

private float ratio;

public FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    fillFromAttrs(context, attributeSet);
}

private void fillFromAttrs(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout);

    ratio = array.getFloat(R.styleable.FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout_ratio, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int originalWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int originalHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int finalWidth = originalWidth;
    int finalHeight = originalHeight;

    if (ratio != 0) {

        if (originalHeight == 0) {
            finalHeight = (int) (originalWidth / ratio);
        } else if (originalWidth == 0) {
            finalWidth = (int) (originalHeight * ratio);
        }

    }
    super.onMeasure(
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(finalWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(finalHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
    );
}
}
```

You also need to specify attribute "ratio" in your res/values/attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout">
    <attr name="ratio" format="float"/>
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

So now you can specify, for example, height of this FrameLayout as you want, set width to 0dp and ratio to 1 and put your ImageView inside this FrameLayout

Also, in ConstraintLayout if you set height to match constraints, you can specify ratio for this view:
[image]

Comment: I didn't use the FrameLayout code you put up, but the tip on the constraint layout did the trick. I have yet to work with it a lot, but I will definitely look into it. Thanks for the help!